# Getting 'command not found' when running daemon in unix

Tags: unix, command, daemon

I am attempting to run the script Daemon.php from a unix prompt as a daemon using the code below as per the instructions given in this [tutorial](http://www.godlikemouse.com/2011/03/31/php-daemons-tutorial/).

```
daemon Daemon.php --log=/var/log/Daemon.log
```

When I run this I get the output

```
daemon: command not found
```

Does know what might be going wrong?

Comment: You may not have `daemon` installed. Try `apt-get install daemon`.

Comment: This returns -bash: get: command not found

Comment: The command isn't `get`, it's `apt-get`.

Comment: My mistake. However running 'apt-get' outputs 'apt-get: command not found'

Comment: Ops, I see you just posted a question about it. apt-get is a tool for package installing in Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try `daemonize` instead. If that also isn't found on your system, simply start `Daemon.php` in the background and see how far you get.